# How to create human readable mongodb records id?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Suppose i want to create a mongodb records, an _id is created automatically. But i want to create this records as an id : 1 and the more records i created, the id will be increased automatically like 2 , 3 ,4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this by creating an id Integer object in the MongoDB model
and increase it, whenever you create a new record

```
const bootcamp = await Bootcamp.find();
const length = bootcamp.length+1
req.body.id = length
await Bootcamp.create(req.body);
```

and then save id along with a new record and you can find your record like that

```
const result = await Bootcamp.findOne({ id: req.body.id})
```

But you cannot edit the _id provide by MongoDB